# How to implement the Facebook SDK in iOS without conflict with IPv6 Network?

Tags: ios, facebook, api, networking, ipv6

Anyone who encountered this issues,

So we got this from Apple,

All apps must support IPv6.

We figured out the bugs in our app is the Facebook SDK 4.6 (Using Safari) doesn't compatible with iPv6 Network. In short, There is an conflict between the Facebook SDK we used. Do we need to change it into Facebook native or Lower version? But we tried already using the lower version of Facebook SDK. Doesn't work at all. What are the possible way to solve the issues?

Appreciate reply.

Thank you in advance.